# Calculate sum of weights for each target for big sparse matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I have a similarity matrix `sim` being rather big `200_000 x 4mio`
which is the similarity between features from "new data" and "old data". To get my prediction I want to create a weighted sum of each class from the "old data". A toy example would be:

```py
target_old_data = ["a", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
sim = [[0.3,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.0],
      [0.2,0.1,0.1,0.5,1.0]]
```

the similarity-sum for each class is then

```py
[{"a":0.4, "b":0.5, "c":0.3},
{"a":0.3, "b":0.5, "c":1.1}]
```

thus we predict  `["b","c"]` for the two new data points.

We can do this rather easy by using pandas:

```py
prediction = []
for row_idx in range(similarity.shape[0]):
         sim_pr_target = pd.DataFrame(
                {"sim": sim[row_idx, :].todense().A1, "target": old_target})
         sim_sum = sim_pr_target.groupby("target")["sim"].sum().sort_values()
         prediction.append(normalized_similarity.index[0])
```

the issue is though that I have a lot of data thus this loop takes rather long time, thus there might be some way to optimize it which I cannot find.